# Replace first whitespace after a character in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, replace, amazon-redshift

I have table like this

```
---------------------------------
| column                        |
---------------------------------
| abc def #ghi jkl mno #pqr stu |
---------------------------------
```

and I want an output that replaces whitespace after every `#` occurrence. I tried using `regexp_replace` but it replaces only the first occurrence.

Expected output:

```
---------------------------------
| column                        |
---------------------------------
| abc def #ghi#jkl mno #pqr#stu |
---------------------------------
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: what was your regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function with a regular expression pattern that matches the whitespace character `(\s)` after a `#` character.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '(#)\s', '\1') AS column
FROM your_table;
```

The resulting output will have all occurrences of whitespace after a `#` character replaced with just the `#` character.

Output :

```
---------------------------------
| column                        |
---------------------------------
| abc def #ghi#jkl mno #pqr#stu |
```

---